# Working password encyption methods for user password managment needed?

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password encryption/ decryption code in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678555/password-encryption-decryption-code-in-net)

Can someone provide working code to encrypt a password and store it in the database.Anything simple would do,some "salt" would be nice.

```
public void Encrypt(string password)
{
}

public void Verify(string password)
{
}
```